# Report Viewer 2012 Redistributable for SQL Server 2012

Tags: reportviewer, sql-server-2012

Just migrating from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012. So I'm facing with trouble: i can't find Report Viewer 2012 Runtime. I found only CTP and Beta Version on Microsoft Downloads. Where can i download it? Thank you.

Comment: According to the beta version download page, it was only released on the 6th June - so my guess is it's highly unlikely a released version is available.